# range slider with reactjs - value changing but slider not moving

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an issue using the library react-input-range (or any other slider): I can see that the value is correctly changing when console.log(value), but the slider doesn't move when I move it... No matter if it's through props or not.

Any idea?

```
import React from 'react';
import InputRange from 'react-input-range';

interface Props {
  min:number;
  max:number;
  step?:number;
  value:any;
  id:string;
}

const RangeSlider = ({ min, max, step=1, value, id }: Props) => {

  
  function onValueChange(newval: any){
    console.log(newval);
    value=newval;
    //some other actions here
  }


  return (
    <div className="slider m-4 mb-6">
        <InputRange
          minValue={min}
          maxValue={max}
          step={step}
          onChange={onValueChange}
          value={value}
        />
      </div>
  );
};

export default RangeSlider;
```

Comment: Move the value into local state as react rerenders on each state change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be an issue with React's props in contrast to using a state.
As found on https://kentcdodds.com/blog/props-vs-state, the DOM isn't updated when a prop changes so your slider won't move.

As suggested by the official documentation of react-input-range, you should rather use state to update and read the value.

Your RangeSlider doesn't extend React.Component so you cannot use state. Of course, I don't know if there is a reason why you don't use something like

```
class RangeSlider extends React.Component {
```

I would suggest you use a class which extends React.Component and then use state for the value. You can then set the state when the value changes, like so (taken from react-input-range's documentation:

```
onChange={value => this.setState({ value })}
```

A proper tutorial for passing props to a component can be found at https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-pass-props-to-component.

*Or, as seen in the other answer, you can of course use the useState hook. (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). You then don't have to extend React's component.*

I hope, this helps out a bit.

Comment: Thank you ! It works well! What i'm wondering now is how to send it to the parent component as I was trying to use the props directly - more investigation needed :)

Comment: @Maxiss You can declare a method in your parent class which handles the state change and pass the method as a prop to the child. Using the React Context API could also be a way to solve your problem. You can have a look at the different methods here: https://www.techiediaries.com/access-update-parent-state-child-component-react/. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

You must use State to do this.

```
const [value,setValue] = React.useState(value);

function onValueChange(newval: any){
   setValue(newval)
}
```